# Main menu doesn't show my application launcher (.desktop file)

Tags: linux, ubuntu, ubuntu-10.04

I've just started out learning to program and I'm making a "Radio Scheduler" for my brother as a mini project. I wanted to make an "install" script, which would add an item to Ubuntu's Main Menu. I believe all that is necessary is to create a .desktop file and place it it /usr/share/applications/? This seemed to work fine when I tried it out on 10.10, but I've now tried it on two 10.04 systems (one virtual) and despite it being in the applications folder (so it moved in okay), it isn't showing up at all in the menu...

```
[Desktop Entry]
Name=ARadio
GenericName=Automatic Radio Scheduler
Exec=/home/user/ARadio/AR
Icon=/home/user/ARadio/Icons/AR.png
Terminal=true
Type=Application
Categories=GNOME;AudioVideo;Applications;
```

I'm not entirely sure about some of that (categories for instance), as I just used another file as a reference. But it seemed to work fine on my 10.10 system, so I don't understand why it won't show up on the others? Should be in Sound & Video if I'm correct... I'm still pretty new to Linux, so sorry if I've got anything completely wrong.

Answer (score 0):

Okay, I set it up on another 10.10 system and that also worked. So after a little experimenting, I found that the reason it wasn't showing up on the 10.04 systems was because I left out ...

```
Comment=Automatic Radio Scheduler
```

... which I didn't realise was so important! Now it shows up in the menu as it should :).